# How can I check which files are part of the archive when uploading an app to appstore?

Tags: xcode, submit, archive

always when uploading an app I wonder which files are actually part of the archive that is being uploaded, since I have many supportive files in my xCode project folder which are not really part of the code but just some documents.
Will they be part of the archive and visible to the installers later or are only those files included in the archive that are referenced in xCode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all the files will be in archive (.app file) and you can see its content by right click on it and select "show package content"

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but when I look at the archive I see only three entries: dSYMs Folder with only one dSYMs file, Info.plist, and one Products/Applications/xx.app. So it seems that it only includes the compiled code and all the other required stuff, but not the other files. I don't know, however, if there is anything within these 2 Files?

Comment: One more comment - on the Mac I can't dig deeper. Also HexEdit on Mac does not open anything. Then I copied the files to PC and checked there. Here you will find all the files that are actually included. NO SUPPORTING FILES are included, as long as they are not really part of the xCode Project!!!

Comment: yes.. the files only get added if you drag and drop them in your project and add there reference in your project. you can right click on .app file and select "show package content" to view your setup included files